# Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size' though I update pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have gone through the previous fixes for the error and updated my 'mysql-connector' to latest version and even changing on to different versions. However I am getting the same error without any changes.(error seems to be stating that I am using mysql-connector 5.1.39 regardless of changing on pom.xml and updating the project) following is the error that I am encountering. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:3833) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3283) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2297) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Try running `mvn dependency:tree` to see from where older version of mysql connector is being picked up. If that doesn't yield any positive results, ensure the classpath is updated to use to right connector jar. You might just need to reimport/refresh the project.

Comment: Can you please show your database connection url?

Comment: @Simon 
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/universe?useSSL=false

Comment: Do you have the String query_cache_size anywhere in your code or persistence.xml

Comment: there is a maven module that automatically downloads mysql-connector 5.1.39 though I have not added it as a dependency in that module.(my project is a combination of six modules) I tried to remove it but I could not do it. :(